# How to label my own point cloud data to have the 3D training labels (.txt) files like KITTI 3D object detection dataset?

Tags: object-detection, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, lidar, kitti

I am new to this field, I have collected some point cloud data using lidar sensor and camera and now I have .pcd files for the point cloud and .png files for the images. I wanted to make this data like the KITTI dataset structure for 3d object detection to use it in a model that uses kitti dataset as training data for 3D object detection. Therefore I want to change my .pcd files to .bin files like in kitti and also I need to have .txt files for labels, so i need to annotate my data in such a way that will give me the same label files like in kitti dataset. Can somebody help me ?. I searched a lot and all the labelling tools don’t output the same attributes that are in the .txt files of KITTI.
This is the link for the KITTI 3D dataset.
http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_object.php?obj_benchmark=3d

Answer (score -2):

There is a lot of different questions in your post, so I'm going to answer those I can. Here is a snippet of code how you can read pcd file:

```
import open3d as o3d
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("../../path_to_your_file.pcd")
#print(pcd)
```

and then you can format it as you want, including writing to binary.
This could be a helpful library, check this out

[link to open3D docs](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/index.html)

[link to open3D github](https://github.com/jhultman/vision3d)

You can get more references from below -
https://paperswithcode.com/task/3d-object-detection